How to make a transporter that releases an item and always take it back right after?
I am working on a model that works like that: there is a agent (uld) coming and brings 10 items. these items are then moved by a transporter (forklift) to a particular zone. In that zone (in theory), they drop the item, wait a few seconds, and take it back and place it in a storage zone.
Originally, I wanted the forklift to not drop the item, just go in the node, wait a bit and go to the final location. I couldn't figure out how to make it happen without releasing the item, so I let the release happen. Now, in most case, it works fine: the forklift drops the item, wait, takes it back and stores it. But sometimes, when too many uld are coming and drop too many items, it seems like the forklift goes straight for a new one instead of storing the item first.
Is there a way, either to make it like the items aren't released, or is there a way that the same forklift always retake its item?
here is the zone where the forklifts are supposed to drop and retake the item
here is the logic I used for the movement of the forklift to the zone
here is the moveby logic
here is the store logic

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Originally, i wanted the forklift to not drop the item, just go in the node, wait a bit and go to the final location. I couldn't figure out how to make it happen without releasing the item

You can do it if you have a MoveByTransporter1-Delay-MoveByTransporter2 flow, where you don't release the transporter in MoveByTransporter1 and don't seize one in MoveByTransporter2.
But since you're using a Store block afterwards, which currently cannot work with already seized transporters, I suggest using the Link to agents. This way your forklift and item can stay connected even after release and they can "find eachother" again. For this example, let's call your agent types Uld and Forklift. (You need custom agent types to be able to use Links)

Create a bidirectional single link between your Uld and Forklift agents. Name them myForklift and myItem.
You want to seize a free forklift, which does not have a connected item. In your MoveByTransporter blocks, enable Customize transporter choice and write this condition into Transporter choice condition: ((Forklift)unit).myItem.isConnected()==false. To connect the item and forklift, put this line into On seize transporter of the same block: agent.myForklift.connectTo((Forklift)unit)
To use the same forklift for storing the item, enable Customize transporter choice in your Store blocks too, and write the following code into Transporter choice condition: agent.myForklift.getConnectedAgent().equals(unit). Too free up the forklift after it finished the task, write this line into On release transporter of the Store block: ((Forklift)unit).myItem.disconnect()


Hello @mczandrea, I did what you proposed, it seems that it can solve this issue, but now when the forklift takes the item in the zone, when it enters the store block and has to take the item back, i have a NullPointerException, on this line : ((Forklift)unit).myBox.getConnectedAgent().equals((Box)agent)
i guess that it doesn't recognise the forklift that is connected to the item.
i just added a myForklift link to agents in the agent Box, and a myBox link to agents in the agent Forklift. theyre both bidirectional single link

I cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure your links are set up correctly? So above the Make unidirectional button of your myForklift link it tells you, that "This link is bidirectional with myBox"?

Yes, i have the correct message

it seems like the transporter choice condition waits for a boolean, so i tried something :
if (unit instanceof Forklift && agent instanceof Box) {
Forklift forkliftAgent = (Forklift) unit;
Box boxAgent = (Box) agent;
if (forkliftAgent.myBox != null) {
    Agent connectedAgent = forkliftAgent.myBox.getConnectedAgent();

    if (connectedAgent != null && connectedAgent.equals(boxAgent)) {
        return true;
    }
}

}
return false;

but now, i have an other error : Syntax error on token "=", : expected. but that one is for _value and i don't know how to fix that or what caused that, if it is because the code is miswritten or something else

Ah I'm really sorry, my original logic can throw a nullpointer exception if there are multiple free (unconnected) forklifts when the condition is evaluated. Please use the updated transporter choice condition in step 3. P.S.: you cannot write mutiple lines in that box, you have to use a function if you have more complex logic

Yes ! Thank you very much, it actually worked exactly as intended !
